# C# No se puede convertir implicitamente un valor de un atributo de una clase

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Archivo XML con el análisis sintáctico de un documento basado en constituyentes el cual puede tener nodos anidados (sub árboles de cualquier profundidad).

```
<document>
  <wordcount>181</wordcount>
  <cputime>0.084678</cputime>
  <paragraph>
    <sentence id="1">
      <token begin="4" ctag="DA" end="6" form="El" gen="masculine" id="t1.1" lemma="el" num="singular" phon="el" pos="determiner" tag="DA0MS0" type="article">
       <morpho>
         <analysis ctag="DA" gen="masculine" lemma="el" num="singular" pos="determiner" selected="1" tag="DA0MS0" type="article"/>
       </morpho>
      </token>
  <constituents>
    <node head="1" label="grup-verb">
      <node label="sn">
        <node label="espec-ms">
          <node head="1" label="j-ms">
            <node head="1" leaf="1" token="t1.1" word="El"/></node>
        </node>
        <node head="1" label="grup-nom-ms">
          <node head="1" label="n-ms">
            <node head="1" leaf="1" token="t1.2" word="doctor"/></node>
          <node label="w-ms">
            <node head="1" leaf="1" token="t1.3" word="Fergusson"/></node>
        </node>
      </node>
  </sentence>
 </paragraph>
</document>
```

He definido la estructura de Clases para según la estructura del XML (generado por freeling con formato CoNLL).

```
public class Senses
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sense")]
    public List<Sense> Sense { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "node")]
public class Node
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "head")]
    public string Head { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "leaf")]
    public string Leaf { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "word")]
    public string Word { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node")]
    public List<Node> Nodo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "constituents")]
public class Constituents
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node")]
    public Node Node { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sentence")]
public class Sentence
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "token")]
    public List<Token> Token { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "constituents")]
    public Constituents Constituents { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "paragraph")]
public class Paragraph
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sentence")]
    public List<Sentence> Sentence { get; set; }
}
```

Al cargar el archivo XML con un Enumerador y LINQ me genera el mensaje "No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable en Proyecto.Node. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)". He utilizado conversión ToList() pero continúa el error. Al pie envío el código de la carga. Gracias ed antemano por la ayuda.

```
            XDocument docuXML = XDocument.Parse(TxtCodificado);

            // Carga el archivo y reconoce vocales asentuadas del Español y símbolos. Se debe preveer el lenguaje del texto para
            archivoXML.LoadXml(TxtCodificado);

            IEnumerable<Paragraph> Parrafos = docuXML.Root.Descendants("paragraph")
                .Select(Parrafs => new Paragraph
                {
                    Sentence = Parrafs.Elements("sentence")
                    .Select(Sentencs => new Sentence
                    {
                        Id = (string)Sentencs.Attribute("id"),
                        Token = Sentencs.Elements("token")
                        .Select(complex => new Token
                        {
                            Begin = (string)complex.Attribute("begin"),
                            End = (string)complex.Attribute("end"),
                            Form = (string)complex.Attribute("form"),
                            Gen = (string)complex.Attribute("gen"),
                            Id = (string)complex.Attribute("id"),
                            Case = (string)complex.Attribute("case"),
                            Ctag = (string)complex.Attribute("ctag"),
                            Lemma = (string)complex.Attribute("lemma"),
                            Person = (string)complex.Attribute("person"),
                            Phon = (string)complex.Attribute("phon"),
                            Pos = (string)complex.Attribute("pos"),
                            Tag = (string)complex.Attribute("tag"),
                            Type = (string)complex.Attribute("type"),
                        }).ToList(),
                        Constituents = Sentencs.Elements("constitutens")
                        .Select(constitu => new Constituents
                            {
                                Node = constitu.Elements("node")
                                .Select(Nd => new Node
                                {
                                    Head = (string)Nd.Attribute("head"),
                                    Leaf = (string)Nd.Attribute("leaf"),
                                    Token = (string)Nd.Attribute("token"),
                                    Word = (string)Nd.Attribute("word"),
                                    Label = (string)Nd.Attribute("label"),
                                    Nodo = Nd.Elements("node")
                                    .Select(Nod => new Node
                                    {
                                        Leaf = (string)Nod.Attribute("leaf"),
                                        Token = (string)Nod.Attribute("token"),
                                        Word = (string)Nod.Attribute("word"),
                                        Label = (string)Nod.Attribute("label"),
                                        Head = (string)Nod.Attribute("head"),
                                    }).ToList()
                                })
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                });
            return Parrafos.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

En la clase Constituents defines la propiedad

```
public Node Node { get; set; }
```

pero deberia ser

```
public List<Node> Node { get; set; }
```

o sea una `List<T>`

Sino en el linq no deberias usar un `Select()` sino un `FirstOrDefault()` para que retorna solo un elemento `Node`

Por otro lado deberias ver de cerrar el tag `<constituents>`, entiendo debería estar arriba de `</sentence>` abarcando los nodos